# Data bars with Data tables

Tags: r, dt

I am trying to add data bars in the columns of the table following below steps:

```
library(DT)
options(DT.options = list(pageLength = 5))
df = as.data.frame(cbind(matrix(round(rnorm(50), 3), 10), sample(0:1, 10, TRUE)))
datatable(df) %>% formatStyle(names(df),
  background = styleColorBar(range(df), 'lightblue'),
  backgroundSize = '98% 88%',
  backgroundRepeat = 'no-repeat',
  backgroundPosition = 'center')
```

The bars are showing from right to left in the cells, i want them to show from left to right. What can be done within data table to modify these data bars.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an argument `angle` th `styleColorBar` that should do the job

```
library(DT)
options(DT.options = list(pageLength = 5))
df = as.data.frame(cbind(matrix(round(rnorm(50), 3), 10), sample(0:1, 10, TRUE)))
datatable(df) %>% formatStyle(names(df),
                              background = styleColorBar(range(df), 'lightblue', angle = -90),
                              backgroundSize = '98% 88%',
                              backgroundRepeat = 'no-repeat',
                              backgroundPosition = 'center')
```

From `help("styleColorBar")`:

> angle
> a number of degrees representing the direction to fill the gradient relative to a horizontal line and the gradient line, going counter-clockwise. For example, 90 fills right to left and -90 fills left to right